# Standard notation for permutations

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, permutations, notation, permutation-cycles

I have a question about the standard notation for representing properties of permutations. This is best illustrated with a concrete example: let's take a permutation on 6 elements with cycle representation $\sigma=(134)(2)(56)$. We know that the cycle representation is unique. In the problem I'm working on, I need an abstract notation to refer to the set of cycles in the cycle representation of $\sigma$. In this example, this set is just $\{(134),(2),(56)\}$, but I don't know a technical name for this set and I imagine one exists. Could anyone point me to a reference which introduces standard notation of this type? So far I haven't been able to find one.

There are some other properties which I would like to give a name to. For example, once the cycle representation of a permutation is written down, we can talk about things like the set of elements acted on by a particular permutation. In my example above, the first cycle acts on the elements $\{1, 3, 4\}$, and it would be nice to have a standard notation for how to index into this subset of the original six elements.

Comment: Well,  I'm not perfectly clear on what you need but Fraleigh is my favorite reference.    Any introduction should be fine.    There's a number of them.

Comment: $(134)$ *fixes* everything but $1,3,4.$

Comment: It's not clear what you need from the notation that you don't already have. It might be clearer if you showed how your proof works up to the point where you need the new notation, then say (with reference to the proof written so far) what you're trying to write in a formula.

Comment: It's not that I need anything deep from this notation, but the argument I'm writing up will eventually be published in a journal and I would like to avoid reinventing notation unnecessarily. My thinking was that people here might know if there are standard symbols for the objects in my question. If not, that's fine, I'll make up a reasonable notation.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this (sort of thing)?

$(134)$ can be "described" by:  $$\begin {pmatrix}1&2&3&4&5&6\\3&2&4&1&5&6\end {pmatrix}.$$

Because $1\to3,2\to2,3\to4,4\to1,5\to5,6\to6.$